# Passing CodeIgniter post data to a function

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

Basically I want my multi-part form's controller to have a single function that gives the post data to the other functions like preview and edit.

The function is below:

```
function get_post_data()
{
  $post_data_array = array();
  // declaration of all form field names
  $variable_array = array('form_field_1', 'form_field_2', ... 'form_field_n');

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($variable_array); $i++) {
    $variable_value = $this->input->post($variable_array[$i]);
    // turn them into an easy-to-use array
    $post_data_array[$variable_array[$i]] = $variable_value;
  }
  return $post_data_array;
}
```

So that functions will access it as:

```
function show_preview_form()
{
  $this->load->view('preview_form_view', $this->get_post_data() );
}

function send_to_database()
{
  $data_array = $this->get_post_data();
  $this->Model->insert_to_database($data_array['form_field_1'], ...);
}
```

Currently it does not work. Firebug returns a `500 Internal Status Error` status. Do you guys know how to solve this?

I really don't want to repeat the long `get_post_data` in every function that needs it.

Comment: What do u see in the error log?

Comment: @Josh - NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Im guessing this is the log from firebug. We need the server log which should be in php_error.log, apache_error.log or some file like that depending on your server os version combination.

Comment: Or you can increase temporarily the log level so it will be output as the response. (You do that in code-igniter by setting the environment to development in the index.php file)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `php_error.log`
I found out that one of my functions is not working :)

Comment: did it fix this problem though?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my vague answer.

Comment: @Josh - hey, do you think my other functions can access the post data? I mean after loading my `preview_form_view`, there is a button that asks if the user wants to save the data to the database. It will then call `send_to_database()`. How will these post data be persistent? I don't know if `flashdata` or `userdata` will work since they have size restrictions (I have `pdf` files to upload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign a empty array to `$post_data_array` before can add values to it.

in the beginning of `get_post_data` function add `$post_data_array = array();`

### update:

its probably also a good idea to change `get_post_data` to `_get_post_data` that way its not accessible directly from the url.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help. I heeded your advice to insert the data in hidden inputs. It's working perfectly now ^_^

Comment: you got to be careful for it not to break your html though. escaping characters if needed...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this?

you can get the post data as an array with..

```
$post_data = $this->input->post();
```

...

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, simply you can use

```
               $this->input->post();
```

to get the input field post data.
And further you can check input post field by set_rules as

```
                     $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName','Username','trim|regex_match[/^[a-z,0-9,A-Z_ ]{5,35}$/]|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFirstName', 'First name','trim|regex_match[/^[a-z,0-9,A-Z_ ]{5,35}$/]|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userLastName', 'Last name','trim|regex_match[/^[a-z,0-9,A-Z_ ]{5,35}$/]|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail', 'Email', 'trim|regex_match[/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/]|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPass', 'Password', 'trim|regex_match[/^[a-z,0-9,A-Z]{5,35}$/]|required|xss_clean|md5|callback_check_database');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //your view to show if validation is false
    } else {
         $user_name = $this->input->post('userName');
        $userfname = $this->input->post('userFirstName');
        $userlname = $this->input->post('userLastName');
        $useremail = $this->input->post('userEmail');
        $userpass = $this->input->post('userPass');
        }
```